# Channel.Security.Error in Flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, security, soap

I have a Flex application running on several domains (HTTP). The application communicates with the server using, among other things, WSDL service that resides on HTTPS.

For reasons unknown (to me), *sometimes* I see a log entry that tells me something like this:

`[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Sikkerhetsfeil ved tilgang til URL-adresse" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Mål: DefaultHTTP"] messageId="D2B72EF4-65FD-4A36-6117-D4DC95E63E01" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]`

I managed to deduce from looking this error up on that it has something to do with SOAP calls.
I tried applying some extra entries to the `crossdomain.xml` based on [this info](http://dotanything.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/flex-security-error-accessing-url-or-channelsecurityerror/), but it didn't really help.
The current content of the crossdomain.xml is as follows:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The most maddening thing is that this error only occurs very sporadically, and is not consistent in any immediately recognizable way.

Anyone? A clue as to why could this be happening?